# Foreign key to User table in django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm using django's built-in contrib.auth module and have setup a foreign key relationship to a User for when a 'post' is added:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User')
    # ... etc.
```

Now when it comes to actually adding the Post, I'm not sure what to supply in the owner field before calling save().  I expected something like an id in user's session but I noticed User does not have a user_id or id attribute.  What data is it that I should be pulling from the user's authenticated session to populate the owner field with? I've tried to see what's going on in the database table but not too clued up on the sqlite setup yet.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I'd like to know how to add the User in the Foreignkey field in my model. Not sure if I get the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to provide a "User" object. I.e. the same kind of thing you'd get from User.objects.get(pk=13).

If you're using the authentication components of Django, the user is also attached to the request object, and you can use it directly from within your view code:

```
request.user
```

If the user isn't authenticated, then Django will return an instance of django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser. (per http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes)

Comment: I am using decorator @login_required before this so hopefully the user should always be authenticated.   Quite different to what I know from PHP... thanks for the help.

Comment: That'll do it - all that's really needed is the 'django.contrib.auth' under INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file.

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements --> Django 3, python 3**

**1)** For add username to `owner = models.ForeignKey('User')` for save that, in the **first step** you must add  `from django.conf import settings` above `models.py` and edit `owner = models.ForeignKey('User')` to this sample:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, allow_unicode=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**2)** And for show detail `Post`, special owner name or family or username under the post, you must add the following code in the **second step** in `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
.
.
. 

def detailPost(request,slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'instance': instance,
    }
return render(request, template_name='detail_post.html', context=context)
```

**3)** And in the **third step**, you must add the following code for show user information like user full name that creates a post:

```
<p class="font-small grey-text">Auther: {{ instance.owner.get_full_name  }} </p>
```

now if you want to use **user name**, you can use `{{ instance.owner.get_username  }}`
or if you want to access short name, you can use `{{ instance.owner.get_short_name  }}`.
See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/) for more information.